# How to send JSON response from python server to the javascript using ajax call

Tags: javascript, python, json, ajax

```
elif self.path == "/recQuery":
  r = requests.get('http://example.com') # This returns some json from a request to another server.
  print r.json()
  self.wfile.write(r.json())
```

.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = SERVER + "/recQuery";
var params = JSON.stringify({
  query: search_query
});
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(params);
console.log(http.responseText);
```

How can i send data from python server to javascript using ajax call. The one i am using does not return anything in the console. Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong here. I need send the response of what i get from requests.get method to the ajax call. The json should be returned to the ajax call in response. Problem is with the self.wfile.write method, When i use this i dont get anything on javascript side.

Comment: It's massively unclear what you are trying to do. What is the first snippet? What are you doing with `requests.get()`?

Comment: http.responseText need to be inside http.onreadystatechange calllback and the content-type should be application/json if you're sending JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/4265939](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/4265939)

Comment: I made an edit just to make my question more clear.

Comment: Thanks @jcubic. Works pretty well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = SERVER + "/recQuery";
var params = JSON.stringify({
  query: search_query
});
http.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    console.log(http.responseText);
  }
};
http.open("POST", url, true);
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.send(params);
```

I was not fetching the response onreadystatechange. So this works for me. Thanks !